# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I'm getting this error when I generate my report. It says "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

How can I solve this? Can anyone help me with this? I am new to vb.net programming. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportFilter) Then
   daEmployee.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({3}) AND a.employee_id IN({4}) group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId))
Else
   daEmployee.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({3}) AND a.employee_id IN({4}) group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId))
End If
```

Comment: Your `string.Format` needs 5 arguments ({0} - {4}), and you are passing only 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need five replacement  parameters for `string.Format` and you have passed only two. you are accessing {2},{3},{4} index parameters which aren't passed.

```
daEmployee.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({3}) AND a.employee_id IN({4}) group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId, another-three-parameters-here))
```

Comment: after employeeId pass three more parameters that would take the place of {2},{3},{4} in the query.